# Jmeter on linux command line able to run only limited number of threads

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter test plan which has run 40000 threads and ramp up time is  600 seconds.
I am running it with command line.

```
./jmeter -n -t ../../HttpTestPlan.jmx
```

It runs fine on windows 64 bit machine. It able to execute all 40000 threads without any problem.

But when I run the same test plan in ec2 (with root privilege) it can execute only 31208 threads and then it will stop the execution.

What should I do to make sure it runs all the threads on linux ec2 box?
Thanks

```
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,148 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_EN
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,164 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: user.properties
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,165 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: system.properties
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,170 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2018 The Apache Software Foundation
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,170 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 4.0 r1823414
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,170 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_181
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,170 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,170 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Linux
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,170 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,170 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,171 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,171 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =1073741824
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,171 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =2
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,175 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (EN)
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,175 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (EN)
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,175 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=/home/pardema/apache-jmeter-4.0
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,175 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/home/pardema/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,176 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =/home/pardema/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,180 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: xxxxxxxxxx Name: xxxxxxxxxxx: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,183 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/home/pardema/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin'
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,189 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/home/pardema/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/../..'
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,336 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,355 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,360 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 4.0
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,366 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: ../../HttpTestPlan.jmx
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,409 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,409 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,409 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,409 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,410 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,410 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,433 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Creating summariser 
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,440 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,441 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,441 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,445 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,445 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,851 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Running test (1536149098851)
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,890 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,891 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 50000 threads for group Thread Group.
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,891 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,891 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=50000 ramp-up=600 perThread=12.0 delayedStart=false
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,900 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,913 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,919 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = 10-118-9-93.ebiz.verizon.com
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,925 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,932 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-3
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,933 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,933 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,933 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,933 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,946 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-4
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,950 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-5
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,962 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-6
    2018-09-05 08:04:58,975 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-7
    2018-09-05 08:04:59,001 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-9
    2018-09-05 08:04:59,006 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-8
    2018-09-05 08:04:59,026 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-10
    2018-09-05 08:04:59,026 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-11
```

Comment: What error do you get ? can you show it ? and also show jmeter.log ?

Comment: It just exists after 31208 threads, no error on console.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to amend [`/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136854/understanding-the-difference-between-pid-max-ulimit-u-and-thread-max) setting

Also check [limits.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf) as you may need to increase the maximum number of open handles

Be aware that 40k threads is quite big amount for a single JMeter engine so you might need to consider [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) , ensure that the machine(s) have enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, network, disk IO, etc. as if JMeter will not be able to send requests fast enough you will get lower throughput even if your application will not be overloaded and stick to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you had a hs_err_pid.log file generated due to crash of your JVM.
Search for such file for root cause of JVM crash.

Among hypothesis:

- Linux memory, process, file descriptor limits
- Not enough memory on your system

Note that 40k threads requires a powerful machine and most probably more than one to overcome:
- network limits of your card
- CPU
- Other resources required

Your machine (2 CPUs , 1Gb RAM) is very very short for that.